# How to figure out missing dll's

Tags: windows, dll, linker, dynamic-linking

I have a MATLAB mex file which does not work, giving me the "The specified module
could not be found." error. Now, I understand that probably the issue is that it tries to link\call\whatever dll's which are missing. I'd like to figure out which ones so that I can provide them.

[Here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92362-how-do-i-determine-which-libraries-my-mex-file-or-stand-alone-application-requires) it is explained how to use the Dependency Walker to generate a text file which supposedly has this information. I generated the file but it's a huge one and I am at a loss as to where exactly the information about the missing files is.

I am thus looking for advice on how to locate the missing files reports in the Dependency Walker output.

Answer (score 2):

One way might be to run [Process Monitor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896645.aspx), filter (Ctrl+L) processes to matlab.exe,  and inspect lines with 'file name not found' immediately after calling your mex.

I can suggest another way - but it is [more complicated and involves attaching a debugger to matlab](http://ofekshilon.com/2013/06/22/entry-point-not-found-and-other-dll-loading-problems/). Don't go there unless Process Monitor fails to address this.